# Moving Folder Redirection Policy to another policy object

Tags: folder-redirection

This is on Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 7 on the workstations.

Let's say I have Documents folder redirection set on GPO1. But, I would like to move that policy to a new GPO2. The target folders on workstation and server side will remain the same, BTW. I just want to isolate the redirection in its own policy -- apart from GPO1 -- and also add Desktop redirection.

What would the behavior be? Will the server/workstaion think this is a new policy and try to undo the redirection and redo it? Or will Windows understand what's happened and leave the folders and sync relationship alone?

Comment: Good question. Technically, the options you set for Folder Redirection upon Policy Removal should take effect because you're removing the policy. The fact that you'll be linking a policy with identical redirection settings should result in the same Folder Redirection being applied but I'm curious if anyone's actually done this and what the result was.